# Splitting up Variance over components

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, probability-theory

If $f\colon [0,1]^n\to\mathbb{R}$ and we take variance wrt the Lebesgue measure(s), do we have

$
Var(f)\leq\sum_{k=1}^n \int_{[0,1]^{n-1}}Var f^k_{\tilde{x}}\;d\tilde{x}
$

where $f^k_\tilde{x}(x)=f(\tilde{x}_1,\dots,\tilde{x}_{k-1},x,\tilde{x}_{k},\dots,\tilde{x}_{n-1})$?

I only get the inequality with an additional factor $n$, by writing

$Var(f)=\frac{1}{2}\int (f(x_1,\dots,x_n)-f(y_1,\dots,y_n))^2\\
=\frac{1}{2} \int_{[0,1]^{2n}} (\sum_{k=1}^n f(y_1,\dots,y_{k-1},x_k,\dots,x_n)-f(y_1,\dots,y_{k-1},y_{k},x_{k+1},\dots,x_n))^2 \\
\leq 
n\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2}\int_{[0,1]^{2n}} (f(y_1,\dots,y_{k-1},x_k,\dots,x_n)-f(y_1,\dots,y_{k-1},y_{k},x_{k+1},\dots,x_n))^2 \\
=n\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{[0,1]^{n-1}} Var f^k_\tilde{x}\;d\tilde{x}
$